# excel sheet to dataset c#

Tags: c#, excel

i'm currently using oledb for getting excel data to dataset/datatable in c#. so far it works but i encountered a problem in getting excel sheets. i have this code in getting the data from excel to dataset

```
bool ret = false;

        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        string strConn;
        try
        {
            if (filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            {
                strConn = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;""", filePath);
            }
            else
                strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;'";

            //SELECT * FROM [{0}$A5:BE] dont accept all sheet names
            string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$A6:BH]", sheetname);

            OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strConn);
            adap.Fill(dset, "SignalList");
```

my problem is this select statement where i get the excel data. sometimes it accept this select statement:

```
 String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$A6:BH]", sheetname),
```

and sometimes it accepts this statement:

```
String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0} $A6:BH]", sheetname)
```

Am i doing something wrong on getting data on excel? sorry for my english. please help

Comment: Where's the `sheetname` coming from? Is it possible for you to debug the code and see the result of the `String.Format` when it works and when it does not work?

Comment: the sheetname came from the loaded excel file. i am currently creating a program where i could get the excel data then transfer it to database. my only problem is that it doesn't accept all sheetnames. all the sheetname format are the same.

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Signal List [sheetname]$A6:BH'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Signal List [sheetname]$A6:BH' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator. this is the error that i always get. i tried to put a space between the sheetname and the range and it worked but it doesn't work in all of the sheetnames that i load in the program. i am thinking that i should make a condition statement to make it work

Comment: it may be that you are missing an exclamation mark after the sheet name. It should always be `Sheet2!A1:A10`

Comment: What is the value of `sheetname` when it accepts `String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$A6:BH]", sheetname);` as opposed to `String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0} $A6:BH]", sheetname);` Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: i figured out that the some of the excel sheetnames have spaces in the last character of the string, which is why i get some errors. i just deleted all the spaces on the first and last string of the sheetname so i wont have any problems. thanks anyway for the help :D